# problem with NHibernate and iSeries DB2

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, ibm-midrange

Ok So I have an AS400/iSeries running v5r4. I have an application that was using classic NHibernate to connect and do some basic crud. Now I have pulled that app (which sat for 2 years) off the shelf of TFS and onto a new PC and cannot seem to get it running.

Here is my Hibernate Config:

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.provider">
        NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider
      </property>
      <property name="dialect">
        NHibernate.Dialect.DB2400Dialect
      </property>
      <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">
        DataSource=207.206.106.19;
        Database=AS400;
        userID=XXXXXX;
        Password=XXXXXXX;
        LibraryList=FMSFILTST,BEFFILT,HRDBFT,HRCSTFT,J20##X2DEV,GLCUSTDEV,OSL@@F3DEV;
        Naming=System;
        Initial Catalog=*SYSBAS;
      </property>
      <property name="use_outer_join">true</property>
      <property name="query.substitutions">
        true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'
      </property>
      <property name="show_sql">false</property>
      <mapping assembly="BusinessLogic" />
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
```

I have all the proper DLL's included (NHibernate, castle, iesi, antlr3 , log4 etc). Also have this line in my web.config

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding>
      <qualifyAssembly partialName="IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries" fullName="IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries,Version=10.0.0.0,PublicKeyToken=9CDB2EBFB1F93A26,Culture=neutral"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Yet I am still getting the following error as soon as I call

```
NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration().Configure().BuildSessionFactory().OpenSession();
```

The error is as follows

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Connection'
>   to type 'System.Data.Common.DbCommand'

I am dying to get some help with this. Any assistance is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: 1. What version of NHibernate are you using? 2. Can you open the iDB2Connection type and see if it indeed doesn't inherit from DbCommand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this issue when using V5r4 of the iSeries system access.  The IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.dll is compiled against .NET 1.0/1 before v6r1.  Because of this it is unable to cast the IDB2Connection to IDbConnection.  If you use reflector and look into the IBM dll, look under references and then look at System.Data version.  Then look at the version of System.Data you are referencing in your project, I am guessing you are on 2.0.5****.  If you upgrade to v6r1 or higher you should be able to cast.

Edit: Wanted to give [Steve Bohlen](http://blog.unhandled-exceptions.com/) credit for leading me down the path to discover this.

Comment: Sorry for the late response on this. I think this is the answer. We have had nothing but problems with V5r4 and upgrading to 6r1, while in the cards, wont happen for a long time. Our iSeries powers our entire company with a 7 terbyte database and thousands of rpg objects on it so its not an upgrade they are taking lightly. Thanks for the response on this.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.  It's amazing how little information there is on this topic.

Comment: do you think if i just get the v6r1 version of the drivers i will be able to hit my v5r4 box with it? or is that under the hood somewhere that i cant get to it? (i.e. the drivers decide what version to use)

Comment: Actually, I must not have had my coffee yesterday when I replied.  Yes, I simply upgraded the dll in the project and was able to hit the box which is on V5r3 here I believe.  So I don't think you would need to upgrade the version the servers sit on, just the reference you are using for access.

Comment: Struggling to find a link to the latest drivers. Any chance of getting one more bone?

Comment: The .NET driver will be in the IBM Client Access application directory. Since they are just wrappers around unmanaged code, you can't just copy the drivers---you need to run your application on a box with IBM Client Access.

Comment: If you can't get a box with v6r1 (or greater), you'll be stuck with a version of NHibernate that doesn't use System.Data.Common. I believe the last such version was 2.0.1. The v6r1 and v7r1 client drivers are backwards compatible with v5r3/4, so if you can find a box with an updated version of client access, you should be fine. Just remember that any box your applications runs on will also need the same version of client access.

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">
NHibernate.Driver.DB2400Driver
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by changing the reference to IBM.Data.DB2.dll to copy local